# How to highlight the menu item for the sort type of data on the page?

Tags: javascript, css, menu

[In this site](http://ting-1.appspot.com/displayimage) I would like to highlight the type of sort on the menu. I found many source to do this with css or javascript but I could not understand them enough to apply them to this site (they seem to be for pull-down menus). Can you direct me about how to do this with the css that I have now for this page? It is just one page, sorted 5 different ways. My `main.css` is below. Thanks!

```
.admin-content {width: 95%; 
margin-top: 0px 
margin-bottom: auto; 
margin-right: 5px; 
margin-left: 5px; 
padding: 0px;}

.image-submit {width: 550px; margin-top: 0px margin-bottom: auto; margin-right: 50px; margin-left: 70px; padding: 15px;}

.image-page {width: 90%; padding: 15px;}

body { font-size: small; font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif; }

a:link { color:#000000; text-decoration:none; }
a:visited { color:#000000; text-decoration:none; }
a:hover { text-decoration: underline; color: #0066CC; } 
a:active { text-decoration: none }

tr {font-size: small; font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif; }      

.small {color: #808080; font-size: x-small; }
.xxsmall {color: #808080; font-size: xx-small; line-height:60%}
.small-tags {font-size: x-small; }
.large {color: #0033FF; font-size: 130%; }
.smaller-line-height {line-height:10%}
.medium {font-size: medium; }
```

**Update**

I updated the script according to [Alon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623409/how-to-highlight-the-menu-item-for-the-sort-type-of-data-on-the-page/7623501#7623501) but this is not working. What am I doing wrong?

I added the js to the header:

```
<head>
...
self.response.out.write("""<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
var url = window.location.href,
sort_by = url.split("=");
if (sort_by.length == 2) { 
document.getElementById(sort_by[1]).className = "active";
}</script>""")
...
</head>
```

changed the urls:

```
self.response.out.write("""<p>
<b>sort by:  </b><a href="/displayimage?sort_by=color">color</a> |
<a id="number_of_attorneys" href="/displayimage?sort_by=number_of_attorneys">number of attorneys</a> | 
<a id="number_of_partners" href="/displayimage?sort_by=number_of_partners">number of partners</a> | 
<a id="number_of_associates" href="/displayimage?sort_by=number_of_associates">number of associates</a> | 
<a id="associate_salary" href="/displayimage?sort_by=associate_salary">associate salary</a> | 
</p>""")
```

and I added the `.active { color:red; }` to `main.css`.

```
.active { color:red; }
```

But this is not working as expected. Is `.active { color:red; }` conflicting with `a:active { text-decoration: none }` in the css? I removed `a:active { text-decoration: none }` but it didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your html should be

```
  <a id="number_of_attorneys" href="/displayimage?sort_by=number_of_attorneys">number of attorneys</a> | 
    <a id="number_of_partners" href="/displayimage?sort_by=number_of_partners">number of partners</a> | 
    <a id="number_of_associates" href="/displayimage?sort_by=number_of_associates">number of associates</a> | 
    <a id="associate_salary" href="/displayimage?sort_by=associate_salary">associate salary</a> |
```

your javascript code should be something like

```
var url = window.location.href,
    sort_by = url.split("=");
if (sort_by.length == 2) { 
   document.getElementById(sort_by[1]).className = "active";
}
```

you should also add class active to your css with the highlight style

```
.active { color:red; }
```

Comment: @ Alon: Thanks for your answer. Now I have a better understanding but I could not make the code work. I updated the question with what I did. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i think you should move the code under the html, because it is executed as soon as the page load, and the menu items still didn't load. move the code to the bottom of your html

Comment: @ Alon: Yes, that was the problem now it is working. But there was another problem. The `color:red` in `.active` is not working. I added `font-weight:bold;` and now items show bold only. Do you know why only bold works in this `.active { color:red; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:underline; }`? Thanks again!

Comment: change `color:red;` to `color:red !important;` this will force this style becuase now it conflicts with the `a:link {...}` style

Comment: another option is to just move `.active {....}` line to the bottom of your css file